# How can I check that if a specific name is taking part of a conversation then enable true if not false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLockState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public camMouseLook mouselook;
    public Conversation conversation;
    public ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerCamera.enabled == false ||
            conversationtrigger.conversationEnd == false)
        {
            PlayerController.disablePlayerController = true;

            if (conversation.Dialogues.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < conversation.Dialogues.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (conversation.Dialogues[i].Name == "Navi")
                    {
                        mouselook.enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mouselook.enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerController.disablePlayerController = false;
            mouselook.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

At this part I'm checking if the specific name is taking part of a conversation:

```
if (conversation.Dialogues.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < conversation.Dialogues.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (conversation.Dialogues[i].Name == "Navi")
                    {
                        mouselook.enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mouselook.enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

If the player is taking part of a conversation, set mouselook to true, if not, set the mouselook to false. But when set to false, I also want to check if the:

```
playerCamera.enabled == false
```

The mouselook should be false only if the playerCamera is also false.
And the mouselook should be true only if Navi is part of the conversation even if the playerCamera is false.

Comment: Just a side question: Your code seems somehow familiar .. are you by chance cooperating with or the same person as [dubi-duboni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10565555/dubi-duboni?tab=profile) and [yochi-le](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11302724/yochi-le?tab=questions&sort=votes)?

Comment: @derHugo Yes sorry for that. It's me the same person. I just got my new pc and forgot my other account/s log in details.

Comment: You know that you can simply [merge accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) into one single account? I guess you would have to explain a bit why in your case it's not actually **accidentally** but this would also assure you get all your reputation into one account... And you can always [reset your password](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) actually so forgetting it is not really an argument I guess. Since this is apparently already the second time maybe you should find a way to remember your login details in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                if (conversation.Dialogues[i].Name == "Navi")
                {
                    playerCamera.enabled == true;
                    mouselook.enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerCamera.enabled == false;
                    mouselook.enabled = false;
                }
```

Correct me if i'm missing something here. Not exactly sure why you'd need to

> I also want to check if the:
>
> playerCamera.enabled == false